# How do I open a directory of images in Androids Navite Image Gallery with PhoneGap?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have an app developed and want a link to open a gallery of images. The images are locally bundled and included in my assets/www/img directory.
I would like this to seamlessly resemble the native image gallery.
Is this possible?

I have tried to use the following but cant get a response.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
        }

        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getDirectory("img/china", {create: false, exclusive: false}, getDirSuccess, fail);
        }

        function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
            // Get a directory reader
            var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();

            // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
            directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess,fail);
        }

        var numDirs = 0;
        var numFiles = 0;

        var readerTimeout = null, millisecondsBetweenReadSuccess = 100;

        function readerSuccess(entries) {
            var i = 0, len = entries.length;
            for (; i < len; i++) {
                if (entries[i].isFile) {
                    numFiles++;
                    entries[i].file(fileSuccess,fail);
                } else if (entries[i].isDirectory) {
                    numDirs++;
                    getDirSuccess(entries[i]);
                }
                if (readerTimeout) {
                    window.clearTimeout(readerTimeout);
                }
            }
            if (readerTimeout) {
                window.clearTimeout(readerTimeout);
            }
            readerTimeout = window.setTimeout(weAreDone, millisecondsBetweenReadSuccess);
        }

        // additional event to call when totally done
        function weAreDone() {
           // do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Camera docs cover this. Is this not working for you?

If Camera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, then a photo chooser dialog is shown, from which a photo from the album can be selected.

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Also refer...

Browsing Image Gallery With PhoneGap & Android

I am porting an application I wrote for the iphone over to Android and I wanted to start with the Camera functionality. I looked around and Googled and I could not find where it was documented on how to browse the image gallery on the Android device. I decided to bang out some simple modifications to the existing Camera object to support that functionality for now. I the future, hopefully this is implemented better by the PhoneGap guys and I can put this code out to pasture.

This code needs to be added to the phoneGap.js file. It creates the prototype for the new method for browsing the gallery on the device

```
1   //
2   // add the new prototype to support the browse function
3   //
4   // i have created a new class 'PixCameraLauncher' so I did not have to modify
5   // the original class file provided by PhoneGap
6   //
7   com.phonegap.CameraLauncherProxy.prototype.browseImages = function(quality) {
8       return PhoneGap.exec("com.phonegap.gapTest.PixCameraLauncher", "browseImages", [quality]);
9   };
```

This the modification I made to the CameraLauncher class provided by PhoneGap. Add a new intent to launch the image gallery

```
01  /**
02   * Get a picture from the Image Gallery.
03   *
04   * in DroidGap.onActivityResult, which forwards the result to
05   * this.onActivityResult.
06   *
07   * @param quality
08   *            Compression quality hint (0-100: 0=low quality & high
09   *            compression, 100=compress of max quality)
10   */
11  public void browseImages(int quality) {
12      this.mQuality = quality;
13   
14      // Display camera
15      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
16              android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
17   
18      this.ctx.startActivityForResult((Plugin) this, intent);
19  }
```

Also we need to handle the returned file. I left it simple, but this could be cleaned up a bit What I do is assume that if there is a URI in the data field, then an image has been picked and should be processed by the utility. In the beginning of the

```
1   void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
```

add the code below. This will handle re-assigning the URI to the selected file

```
1   // If image available
2   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
3    
4       //
5       // this means the user selected an image, so just pass it back!!
6       //
7       if (intent.getData() != null) {
8           imageUri = intent.getData();
9       }
```

After a little more testing and code cleanup, I will make the complete project for the android work and the iphone work available. If there are any questions, post it below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to use the File API to read files inside of your applications assets directory. That directory is not actually part of the file system. When you do a window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, ...) you are actually getting the /sdcard (most probably) back. So when you try to load "img/china" that directory does not exist.

You would need to copy the files from your assets directory to the local file system during the onCreate method of your main Java class. Then you can use the DirectoryReader to get a list of all the files.

Alternatively, if you know all the images ahead of time you could create your own JSON file that lists them all. Then load that file and be able to loop through all the entries to create your own gallery.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I do know all my images ahead of time so exploring the JSON option might be my best bet.   Do you have any documentation on how to create my own gallery from the JSON file?

Comment: You'd probably have to role your own. Check out: http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/